# Select according to first two levels of multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Take the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(5),range(5),range(5),range(5)], columns=range('a','e'))
df.set_index(['a','b','c','d'])
subselection = df[0, 2]
```

The second line of code is supposed to fetch the sub-dataframe according to the first level index and second level index.

This doesn't work for me. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with tuples:

```
subselection = df.xs((0, 1), level=[0, 1])
print (subselection)
     e
c d   
2 3  4
  3  4
  3  4
  3  4
```